# How do I make rails routes based on a function, as oppsed to an attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

So in my rails app, the 'page' model has a title. This title can have whitespace be capitalized and the like. How can I define a route for that page based on the output of a function?

Theoretically:

```
def clean_title(title)
  title.downcase.gsub(/\s/, '')
end
```

Normally, I would define the route like so: `match ':title' => 'pages#display'`

Instead of using the title attribute, I would like to use the output of `clean_title`. But how?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question per se, but there is a very good gem for doing something similar called friendly-id https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

friendly_id can be a bit heavy weight. if you don't have to rely on storing a slug for your page, you can calculate the friendly id of your page every time.

there is a [nice example in the rails docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Inflections/parameterize) for how to use `to_param` for implementing this kind of behaviour:

```
  class Person
    def to_param
      "#{id}-#{name.parameterize}"
    end
  end

  @person = Person.find(1)
  # => #<Person id: 1, name: "Donald E. Knuth">

  <%= link_to(@person.name, person_path(@person) %>
  # => <a href="/person/1-donald-e-knuth">Donald E. Knuth</a>
```

and in your controller, instead of `find(params[:id])` you first extract the id part and then search for it.

Comment: Do you have to do anything in routes.rb to make this happen? Or does to_param automatically set the person_path?

Comment: it takes whatever `to_param` spits out as the id part. it should be transparent for the routes